# Properly toggle a hidden table to visible with angular-datatables?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I have 2 tables, one displayed, the other one hidden:

```
<div ng-show="displayed('active')" ng-controller="DataTablesCtrlA as datatables">
  <table datatable="" dt-columns="datatables.dtColumns" dt-options="datatables.dtOptions" class="display"></table>
</div>

<div ng-show="displayed('retired')" ng-controller="DataTablesCtrlB as datatables">
  <table datatable="" dt-columns="datatables.dtColumns" dt-options="datatables.dtOptions" class="display"></table>
</div>
```

I have a toggle which controls the visibility of the tables, when button A is clicked, then table A is displayed and table B get hidden and vice-versa.

The issue I am facing is that when table B get displayed, the table header is not properly expanded. This is known and well explained on DataTables documention [here](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()).

Below a screenshot of the issue:
[image: header collapse issue]

So I am using `columns.adjust()`  like so:

In the View template:

```
<div  class="btn-group">
  <button ng-click="setDisplayed('active')"
                        ng-class="{active: displayed('active')}" class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
  <button id="btn-retired" ng-click="setDisplayed('retired')"
                        ng-class="{active: displayed('retired')}" class="btn btn-default">Retired</button>
</div>
```

In the View controller:

```
//...
this.setDisplayed = function(toDisplay){
    this.displayed = toDisplay;
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust().draw();
  };
//...
```

The issue I am facing is that table B is still hidden when `setDisplayed` get called and the header stay "unexpanded".

Is there a clean way to solve this problem ?

One solution I have in mind would be to listen for changes on the table `display` style attribute and call `colums.adjust()` in the event handler. But this would require to change the directive link property.

Comment: What DataTables version are you using? `$.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} )` only became available in 1.10.8.

Comment: I am using version 1.10.9